# how to assign uninitialized string value from another string in C++

Tags: c++

I am very new to programming. My question may be silly but it will be helpful if someone can guide me.

Please see my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "you have choose to Reverse the text" << endl;

        string inputstring;
        string outputstring;

        cout << "Enter the string you want to reverse" << endl;
        getline(cin, inputstring);
        int n = inputstring.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            outputstring[i] = inputstring[n - 1 - i]; // problem in this line
        }
}
```

Till here it works fine `inputstring[n - 1 - i]` but when I try to assign its value to `outputstring`. I am getting error.

Answer (score 3):

`outputstring` is empty, so you're accessing it out of bounds here:

```
outputstring[i] = inputstring[n - 1 - i];
```

You have to ensure `outputstring` has length of at least `n` by the time you enter the loop. There are different ways of achieving that.

One solution is to create it with size `n` *after* reading in to `inputstring`. Here, we create it filled with `*`:

```
std::string outputstring(n, '*');
```

You can also resize the string after creation:

```
outputstring.resize(n);
```

Now you can access `outputstring[N]` for `N` in the range `[0, n)`. This makes your loop valid. See [this working example](http://ideone.com/hzrbSv).

Alternatively, you could consider reversing `inputstring` in-place. Note that in real code, this can be easily done with `std::reverse`:

```
std::reverse(inputstring.begin(), inputstring.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use the `assign` member function of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)

```
 outputstring.assign(inputstring);
```

or you could even simpler use its `operator =` like

```
outputstring = inputstring;
```

Or, if you just want to assign *parts* of the string, you can [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), [replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace), [append](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) and use [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) to resize the string

As a rule of thumb, always read the documentation related to any C++ feature you are using, so **if you use `std::string` you have to read [its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) *before* starting coding** (to be able to choose the right functions for the job)

Reading the first few chapters of a good book on [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) before even typing any C++ code will be very helpful.

OF course learn [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or C++14, not some older version of the standard.

Comment: OP doesn't want to assign the whole string. They want to assign elements. They are attempting to reverse the string.

Answer (score 0):

*outputstring* is empty. So during accessing to its i'th element you program causes undefined behavior ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/), **Exception safety** section) .
Just change last lines

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            outputstring[i] = inputstring[n - 1 - i]; // problem in this line
        }
```

with

```
        outputstring.reserve(n);  // reserve is optional. Use it just for memory allocating optimization..
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            outputstring += inputstring[n - 1 - i]; // problem in this line
        }
```

*Operator +=* appends char or string to initial string.